# Regularization and multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, tikhonov-regularization

Multicollinearity/collinearity, from what I understand, occurs when 2 or more predictor/independent variables (variates) are strongly linearly dependent. This leads to overfitting, and we could use regularization to alleviate such concerns.

I've heard and read some people say that regularization alleviates multicollinearity, but this is not true right? Regularization doesn't actually remove any multicollinearity; it just mitigate its effects on the regression model?

My understanding is multicollinearity is inherent with the dataset. Regularization does not affect the dataset.